# ¿ cómo hacer para insertar los datos de string en la matrix?

Tags: java

Insertar Datos Alumno:
Se selecciona la fila donde desea insertar (o asignar) los datos
Se le solicitan los datos anteriores al usuario y se colocan en las columnas respectivas

-Se debe verificar si la fila ya posee datos

-Se debe verificar si todas las columnas de la fila poseen un valor de 0 (`String`)

> MatrixAlumnos[fila][columna] == “0“

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ArreglosMatrices {

    
    private final int largoArreglo = 5;
    private final int matrizFila = 5;
    private final int matrizColumna = 7;

   
    String arreglo[] = new String [largoArreglo]
    
    int matriz[][] = new int[matrizFila][matrizColumna];//[5][5] = 25 espacios/variables/casillas

    ArrayList<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public ArreglosMatrices() {
        for (int i = 0; i < largoArreglo; i++) {
            arreglo[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    public void insertarDato ( String dato, String indice){
    
    }
      
        
        if (indice >= 0 && indice < arreglo.length) {  
            arreglo[indice] = dato;
        } else {
            
            System.out.println("El indice esta fuera de rango");
        }
    }

    public void imprimirArreglo() {
        System.out.println(arreglo[1]);//[100,200,300,400,500] => 200
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arreglo[i]);
            System.out.println(String.format("El indice %d del arreglo tiene un valor de %d", i, arreglo[i]));
            System.out.println("El indice"+i+"del arreglo tiene un valor de "+arreglo[i]);
        }
    }

    public void AgregarDatoMatriz(int dato, int indiceF, int indiceC) {
        if ((indiceF >= 0 && indiceF < matrizFila) && (indiceC >= 0 && indiceC < matrizColumna)) {
            matriz[indiceF][indiceC] = dato;
        } else {
            System.out.println("El indice esta fuera de rango");
        }
    }

    public void imprimirMatriz() {
        for (int x = 0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("El indiceX %d y indiceY %d de la matrix",x,y));
                System.out.println(String.format("Tiene un valor de %d",matriz[x][y]));
            }
        }
    }
    //Privados 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROCURA NO LLAMAR UN METODO CON EL MISMO NOMBRE DE LA CLASE,A MENOS QUE SEA EL CONSTRUCTOR**

*-Estas declarando la variable arreglo como un arreglo de tipo `String` pero en tu método `ArregloMatrices` insertas 0 que es un `int` ,debes tener presente que cuando declaras un array de tipo String su valores por defecto son `null`si quieres evaluar si algun indice posee dato podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
if(arreglo[indiceDado]!=null){accion}
```

o bien puedes llenarlos de "0"

```
public void arreglosMatrices() {
        for (int i = 0; i < largoArreglo; i++) {
            arreglo[i] = "0";
        }
    }
if(!arreglo[i].equals("0")){accion}
```

*-El indice de un array debe ser de tipo `int`,sin embargo estas pasando como parámetro el indice como tipo `String` en el método `insertarDato()`

```
public void insertarDato ( String dato, int indice){
        if (indice >= 0 && indice < arreglo.length) {  
            arreglo[indice] = dato;
        } else {
            System.out.println("El indice esta fuera de rango");
        }
    }
```

*-Si vas a usar String format,debes tener presente `%d = int %s= String`

```
  public void imprimirArreglo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("El indice %d del arreglo tiene un valor de %s ", i, arreglo[i]));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```